# suitescript 2.0 upload image to netsuite file cabinent with watermark attached to image

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Trying to create an html5 form that uploads an image and automatically adds a watermark. Then it would upload said image with watermark to my netsuite filecabinent. Can this be done via suitescript? If so, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much and happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

SuiteScript has no image manipulation APIs. You'll need to find some third-party tool or service to modify the image file.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that - What I am asking is what api of suitescript should i be calling to have an HTML page with a file upload box - that would essentially go through the image watermark script, then publish the file to my cabinent in a specified folder?

Comment: You can create your own HTML pages within NetSuite by creating a Suitelet script. Use the Suitelet's `GET` request handler to generate the HTML and render the page. Use the `POST` handler to process the submitted file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. you can add a file field in your own html form.
   like,
   `<input type='file' name='re_img' id='re_img'/>` (in **GET** request handler)

`accept='image/x-png,image/jpeg'` (add this tag to your file field if you want to upload only images).

2. Handle it in **POST** request handler like,

var imageFile = request.getFile('re_img');

This will return you an **nlobjFile** instance. you can handle it the way you want.